# web api not working in sub folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My web API is working well but when i write same code in area folder it not working.

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
     {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
         {
             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "FeatureA",
              routeTemplate: "FeatureA/api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );

             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );
       }
   }
```

Comment: What mean `is not working` ? Any errors ?

Comment: 404 page not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your routing details in the "YourHubNameAreaRegistration" class that's in your Area folder.  It goes in the RegisterArea method and should look something like this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
              "Hub_default",
              "api/Hub/{action}/{id}",
              new { controller = "Hub", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
    }
```